# Visual Paradigm: How to generate SQL from E-R diagram with standard SQL types?

Tags: entity-relationship, visual-paradigm

I am currently using Postgres, however, I would like to use standard SQL types for my columns, for portability reasons.

I am attempting to do my modelling in Visual Paradigm Version 14.2 (Build sp1_20180201), under an evaluation license.

I can create an E-R diagram, and when I generate the SQL, Visual Paradigm asks me to select a database configuration before it can do this. So I selected Postgres, but now it converts all my standard types into Postgres specific types! For example, every BIGINT becomes an int8, both in the generated SQL code and the diagram.

Now when I edit the column in the diagram, I can select BIGINT again, but it now appears in italics in the drop down box, and when I save changes to the column, it is int8 again.

How do I successfully generate standard SQL code from an E-R diagram in Visual Paradigm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you specified the database type then the columns will automatically changed to the compatible types for that database. In PostgreSQL the bigint is aliased in int8 and that's why your columns are show in int8 even you manually changed back to bigint. You can override this by defining bigint in **User Type** field of column's specification dialog. Detailed steps can be found at https://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/database-design/custom-column-types/